# Multiple media queries being ignored

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

What I'm trying to do is switch from 3 columns to 2 at <800, then 1 column at <640. I've found that the first query is acknowledged but the following query is ignored. If I swap the queries' places, the same rule applies. For what I used below, I see the max-width: 800px (blue border) work – it still shows at <640px though. The red border never shows.

The markup:

```
<div id="colorPalette_container" class="center clearfix">

    <h1>Color Palette</h1>
        <ul class="colorPalette">
            <li class="bg">#f2ede6 [Background]</li>
            <li class="primary">#0b4167 [Primary]</li>
            <li class="secondary">#00538e [Links]</li>
            <li class="logo">#00a7e0 [Logo]</li>
            <li class="text">#f2ede6 [Text]</li>
            <li class="subtext">#56524d [Sub-text]</li>
            <li class="icons">#0b4167 [Icons]</li>
            <li class="rule">#ffffff [Rules]</li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

The original CSS:

```
#colorPalette_container {
    margin: 3.125em 0 5em 0;
}

    .colorPalette li {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0.625em 3.125em 0;
        padding: 0.313em;
        color: white;
        font: 1.25em/1.6em "Proxima Nova", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .colorPalette li {
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0.312em 3.125em 0.312em;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
};

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .colorPalette li {
            width: auto;
            float: none;
            margin: 0 0 3.125em 0;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because you have a trailing semi-colon after each `@media` rule. Removing them gives you the expected behaviour:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .colorPalette li {
        width: 45%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0.312em 3.125em 0.312em;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .colorPalette li {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 3.125em 0;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tde7r/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 641px)
```

(not tested)